# Trying to delete empty strings from sublists does not work when applying solution to outer list

Tags: python

```
tc = int(input())
case = list(range(tc))

for i in range(0, tc):
    case[i] = input().split("X")

print(case)
```

Inputs are below:

```
5
OOXXOXXOOO
OOXXOOXXOO
OXOXOXOXOXOXOX
OOOOOOOOOO
OOOOXOOOOXOOOOX
```

I entered the inputs, and the result was below.

```
[
    ['OO', '', 'O', '', 'OOO'],
    ['OO', '', 'OO', '', 'OO'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', ''],
    ['OOOOOOOOOO'],
    ['OOOO', 'OOOO', 'OOOO', '']
]
```

I want to delete the empty strings in this list. How can I solve this problem?

I tried the code below.

```
case = list(filter(None, case))
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Hello, what it is your expected output?

Comment: @FrancoGil I expected list without empty strings. I wanted ['OO', 'O', 'OOO'] like this, not like ['OO', '', 'O', '', 'OOO'] this.

Answer (score 2):

You want to remove empty strings from each list *inside* the outer list `case`, but your code says to remove "empty" elements from `case` itself.

`list(filter(None, ...))` is a correct way to do this but you have to apply it to the appropriate lists. The simplest way to adjust your code would be to include it in the `for` loop where you create the inner lists:

```
for i in range(0, tc):
    case[i] = list(filter(None, input().split("X")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

L = ['OOXXOXXOOO', 'OOXXOOXXOO', 'OXOXOXOXOXOXOX', 'OOOOOOOOOO', 'OOOOXOOOOXOOOOX']
out = [re.findall(r'[^X]+', s) for s in L]
```

Explanation from [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9Dls6f/1)

Output:

```
>>> out
[['OO', 'O', 'OOO'],
 ['OO', 'OO', 'OO'],
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
 ['OOOOOOOOOO'],
 ['OOOO', 'OOOO', 'OOOO']]
```

Comment: The python [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) reference could explain a more detailed information about what it is under the hood.

Comment: @FrancoGil I already set the link :) and add a link to regex101

Answer (score 0):

my solution just get focused on the algorithm that will "remove" the "X" char (defined as `target`),
I completely ignore the  first steps related with input steps (reading the input data).

```py
data: list = [
    'OOXXOXXOOO',
    'OOXXOOXXOO',
    'OXOXOXOXOXOXOX',
    'OOOOOOOOOO',
    'OOOOXOOOOXOOOOX'
]

# This is an O(N^2) solution (slower than some other possible approaches):
# The inner `for` loop will split the string creating a new list to iterate.
# Also there is an `if` conditional to filter non-empty `string` objects.
def clean_input(data: list, target: str) -> list:
    out = []
    for line in data:
        out.append( [_ for _ in line.split(target) if _] )

    return out



print( clean_input(data, 'X') )
"""
[
    ['OO', 'O', 'OOO'],
    ['OO', 'OO', 'OO'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['OOOOOOOOOO'],
    ['OOOO', 'OOOO', 'OOOO']
]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the empty strings of a list, you can use a simple list comprehension like: `[string for string in list_ if string]`. Empty strings evaluate to false therefore removing all empty strings.

What you have is a 2D array, so instead you can keep the first list comprehension and add another one to loop over the lists inside.

So it would look something like: `case = [[string for string in list_ if string] for list_ in case]`.

You can also use `filter` here like: `case = [list(filter(None, list_)) for list_ in case]`.

Answer (score -1):

`Try this` :

```py
tc = int(input())
case = list(range(tc))
for i in range(tc):
    case[i] = input().split("x")
    while "" in case[i]:
        case[i].remove("")
```

I hope it's good for you.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
for i in l:
    for j in i:
        if j == "":
            i.remove("")
```

It worked for me.
If you want the output:

```
[['OO', 'O', 'OOO'], ['OO', 'OO', 'OO'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['OOOOOOOOOO'], ['OOOO', 'OOOO', 'OOOO']]
```